# Ruby module include not loading dependent files

Tags: ruby

I have the following structure:

```
lib/models/module_name.rb
lib/models/module_name/one.rb
lib/models/module_name/two.rb
lib/models/module_name/three.rb
```

module_name.rb contains the following:

```
require 'module_name/one'
require 'module_name/two'
require 'module_name/three'
```

When module_name.rb is loaded I get the error 'No such file to load -- module_name/one (LoadError)'

any ideas? Please excuse my ignorance.

Comment: @moderators, please vote to close or delete this post, it's junk.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like the problem was caused by a problem with virtualbox and windows mounting interaction. Basically the files were moved after I performed a move, but the files were not correctly registered in the linux VM and thus could not be loaded by ruby.

Answer (score 3):

Try using:

```
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/module_name/one'
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/module_name/two'
require File.dirname(__FILE__) + '/module_name/three'
```